# Z3 reports "unknown" for some formulas involving (_ as-array ...)

Tags: arrays, z3, decidable

Z3 (version 4.4.1) reports "unknown" for many of the queries generated by a tool I'm writing, and I've narrowed the problem down to the use of `(_ as-array ...)`:

```
(declare-sort MyType)
(declare-fun f (MyType) Bool)
(declare-const a1 (Array MyType Bool))
(declare-const a2 (Array MyType Bool))

; This works fine! (output is SAT)
(push)
(assert (distinct a1 a2))
(check-sat)
(pop)

; This does not! (output is UNKNOWN)
(push)
(assert (distinct a1 (_ as-array f)))
(check-sat)
(pop)
```

Have I fallen into a case that is known to be undecidable (or unimplemented in Z3)?

Comment: Z3 does not support fully as-array. It is returned by model construction, and otherwise is accessible to create constraints, but the array theory does not fully validate final states when there is an occurrence of as-array in the constraints. It then always gives up and Z3 says the state is unknown even though it may very well be the case that there exists an interpretation of the underlying function that satisfies the asserted constraints.

Comment: Hm, that's too bad. Do I have some recourse here? Is there some structured way (like maybe `(assert (forall ((x MyType)) (= (select a x) (f x))))`) to construct an array while still being in Z3's decidable fragment?